# How to mock PerformanceObserver with Jest

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs

I have some code where I am creating a PerformanceObserver in a constructor and I am trying to figure out how to mock it so I can assert both that `observe` is being called on the observer, and also emulate a performance entry being generated, which would cause the callback to be called, and assert that the callback was in fact called. The code in the constructor looks like this:

```
    const { _tracking } = props;

    this.resourceObserver = new PerformanceObserver((list) => {
      const resourceEntries = list.getEntriesByType(
        'resource',
      ) as PerformanceResourceTiming[];

      for (const resource of resourceEntries) {
        resourceObserverCallback(_tracking, resource);
      }
      performance.clearResourceTimings();
    });
    this.resourceObserver.observe({ entryTypes: ['resource'] });
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT:

I can assert that `observe` is called on the observer by creating a `createResourceObserver` function that either returns a passed-in mock or a real `PerformanceObserver`, which solves part of the problem, but I'm still not sure how to exercise the observer in a test.

Here's what the function looks like:

```
createResourceObserver() {
    const { _mockObserver, _tracking } = this.props;

    if (_mockObserver) {
      return _mockObserver;
    }

    const observer = new PerformanceObserver((list) => {
      const resourceEntries = list.getEntriesByType(
        'resource',
      ) as PerformanceResourceTiming[];

      for (const resource of resourceEntries) {
        resourceObserverCallback(_tracking, resource);
      }
      performance.clearResourceTimings();
    });
    return observer;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This needs a long answer.
Working playground example link at the end.

To test something, you must isolate and inject all external dependencies from outside. There are different patterns to do that.

You want to test two things - what happens in the constructor and what happens when the callback is initiated. We will solve those separately.
To test your `PerformanceObserverCallbackHandler`, you need to have it separated callable thing with all external dependencies also injected.

We will isolate and hide the PerformanceObserver behind a singleton Factory so that we can control which implementation is injected and when.

Here is the implementation of the factory

```js
class PerformanceObserverFactory {
  private instance: PerformanceObserver | undefined;
  create(callBack: PerformanceObserverCallback): PerformanceObserver {
    if (this.instance) {
      return this.instance;
    }
    return new PerformanceObserver(callBack);
  }

  setMockedIsntance(mock: PerformanceObserver) {
    if (this.instance !== undefined) {
      throw new Error(
        'Mocked instance is already set. Consider calling reset() in beforeEach()'
      );
    }
    this.instance = mock;
  }

  reset() {
    this.instance = undefined;
  }
}

const instance = new PerformanceObserverFactory();

export default instance;
```

Now, let us tear apart the class. Some external dependencies are not described, so I have faked those to be there. See the `declare global` part. Here is the implementation of the consumer class

```js
import PerformanceObserverFactory from './PerformanceObserverFactory';

export type Handler = (
  tracking: string,
  resource: PerformanceResourceTiming
) => void;

declare global {
  var _tracking: string;
  var resourceObserverCallback: Handler;
}

export class ClassToBeTested {
  private resourceObserver: PerformanceObserver;

  constructor() {
    const callBack = this.getPerformanceObserverCallback(
      _tracking,
      resourceObserverCallback,
      performance
    );
    this.resourceObserver = PerformanceObserverFactory.create(callBack);

    this.resourceObserver.observe({ entryTypes: ['resource'] });
  }

  getPerformanceObserverCallback(
    tracking: string,
    handler: Handler,
    performance: Performance
  ): PerformanceObserverCallback {
    return (list) => {
      const resourceEntries = list.getEntriesByType(
        'resource'
      ) as PerformanceResourceTiming[];

      for (const resource of resourceEntries) {
        handler(tracking, resource);
      }
      performance.clearResourceTimings();
    };
  }
}
```

And last, we have the tests itslef:

```js
import { ClassToBeTested, Handler } from './ClassToBeTested';
import PerformanceObserverFactory from './PerformanceObserverFactory';
import { mock } from 'jest-mock-extended';

describe('ClassToBeTested.constructor', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    PerformanceObserverFactory.reset();
  });

  it('Should subscribe to PerformanceObserver with correct params', () => {
    const observeMock = jest.fn();
    PerformanceObserverFactory.setMockedIsntance({
      observe: observeMock,
    } as unknown as PerformanceObserver);

    const testSubject = new ClassToBeTested();

    expect(observeMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ entryTypes: ['resource'] });
  });
});

describe('ClassToBeTested.getPerformanceObserverCallback', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    PerformanceObserverFactory.reset();
  });

  it('Should call the resourceObserverCallback for eeach list entry and then call clearResourceTimings once', () => {
    const entryListResult: Array<PerformanceResourceTiming> = [
      { name: 'name 1' },
      { name: 'name 2' },
    ] as Array<PerformanceResourceTiming>;
    const resourceObserverCallbackMock = jest.fn();
    const _tracking = 'I do not know what this is';
    const performanceMock = mock<Performance>();
    const entryList = mock<PerformanceObserverEntryList>();
    entryList.getEntriesByType.mockReturnValue(entryListResult);

    PerformanceObserverFactory.setMockedIsntance({
      observe: jest.fn(),
    } as unknown as PerformanceObserver);

    const testSubject = new ClassToBeTested();

    const theCallback = testSubject.getPerformanceObserverCallback(
      _tracking,
      resourceObserverCallbackMock,
      performanceMock
    );

    //lets call it to test it
    theCallback(entryList, mock<PerformanceObserver>());

    expect(entryList.getEntriesByType).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(resourceObserverCallbackMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(
      entryListResult.length
    );
    expect(performanceMock.clearResourceTimings).toHaveBeenCalled();

    // we check that each item in the result list is processed
    entryListResult.forEach((item, index) => {
      expect(resourceObserverCallbackMock).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(
        index + 1,
        _tracking,
        item
      );
    });
  });
});
```

[Here is a link to a fully working example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-ujnvsv?file=package.json,ClassToBeTested.ts,ClassToBeTested.test.ts,PerformanceObserverFactory.ts)

[Factory method pattern link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

[Singleton pattern link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)